Are there stylistic problems with this Renaissance canon study?
I came across this article about a historically informed method to teach canon.
https://symposium.music.org/48/item/2248-so-you-want-to-write-a-canon-an-historically-informed-new-approach-for-the-modern-theory-class.html
Part of the article is about canon above a cantus firmus. If I understood the method, you start by making a skeleton of a pitch in the dux which harmonizes with the c.f. and then move on the the pitch of the comes which also must harmonize with the c.f. The skeleton ends up like a checkerboard of the tones dux/comes. (See the patterns of Zarlino given in example 2 in the linked article.) Then you fill in the "missing" notes to get a 1:1 species type counterpoint in long note values. Finally, diminution is used to embellish the skeleton (see examples 3a and 3b from Morley in the linked article.)
I tried to follow the method and want some feedback on the result.
Mm. 5-6 were hard to fill in so I changed that area and inadvertently ended up with parallel octaves between the bass and middle voice. I marked those with 8s and ! in the score. In the final diminution I tried to hide that problem with a rest.
I haven't studied a lot of Renaissance music so I don't have a great sense for it. I tried to not worry about functional harmony except at the cadence. I mostly tried to handle the vertical intervals like in species counterpoint and tried to avoid any voice-leading or melodic faux pas.
Can anyone point out stylistic problems?
The last system is just the top voices canon without the c.f. bass.

If it helps, this is the table I made of possible dux/comes imitating at the fifth above the moves of a cantus firmus. The c.f. moves are only ascending/descending step, third, and fourth. I was trying to make a more complete table based on the second two patterns given by Zarlino in example 2 from the linked article.


The term comes meaning "follower" is singular, despite the s at the end.  I edited the text of the question but not the musical examples.

Ah, thanks. I'll update my music examples

You're welcome.  I'll try to come up with something more substantive to say about the music after I've had a chance to look at it more closely.

@phoog, hoping you can find time to come back to this canon question :-)

@MichaelCurtis Concerning style, I'll point out the final cadence is a little problematic with the C suspension having a quarter note of dissonance with only an 8th note of preparation.

Sorry.  I did have a look but I had trouble putting my impressions into words and then I went on vacation.  I do have some thoughts that I will try to organize after I return.

Writing canons is a tricky business, and you'll often find yourself wanting to revise the melody either for better melodic shape, or because of bad counterpoint as in this example. There are no especially general rules for this, and we are left to assume that the masters used a lot of trial and error. In this particular instance, bringing the dux down to an E in m. 4 instead of up to an A fixes the problem.
The usual way to write a canon is from start to finish, either beginning with a skeleton as in your second example, or writing the whole thing in one fell swoop. There is no advantage in composing every other note first, and I don't see that technique used in the source you cited.

This "every other note" technique is in the linked article with an example labeled "Example 2: dux-CF progressions in a canon at the fifth above, based on Zarlino's Le istitutioni harmoniche 3rd ed. (1573), p. 308."

Is the only bad counterpoint issue the one you pointed out in m. 4?
